# How to style a div based on the validation status of the all included reactive form fields?

Tags: css, angular, validation, angular-reactive-forms, styling

I have a relative complex form with a multiple fields.
Some of the fields a building the logical blocks, and I want to highlight the surrounding div if any of the included fields are invalid. What could be the best approach to implement it?

Currently I try to implement in following way, but unfortunately stuck in the marked place

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, Validators} from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="form">
      <input formControlName="name">
      <div class="div-address" [class.div-error]="DivHasError(divAddress)" #divAddress>
        <div class="div-text">Address</div>
        <input formControlName="addressType">
        <div formGroupName="address">
          <div>
            <input formControlName="street">
          </div>
          <div>
            <input formControlName="city">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  `,
  styles: [
    `
      input.ng-invalid {border-color: red;}
      .div-error .div-text {color: red;}
    `
  ]

})
export class AppComponent {
  protected form = this.fb.group({
    name: ['', Validators.required],
    addressType: ['office', Validators.required],
    address: this.fb.group({
      street: ['', Validators.required],
      city: ['', Validators.required],
    })
  });
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  }

  DivHasError(divElement: HTMLDivElement): boolean {
    //TODO: How to find out which fields are included and if they are valid in more generic way?
    if (! (this.form.get(['addressType'])?.valid ?? true)) return true;
    if (! (this.form.get(['address','street'])?.valid ?? true)) return true;
    if (! (this.form.get(['address','city'])?.valid ?? true)) return true;
    return false;
  }
}
```

Obviously I want to have a generic solution, not to list all the fields manually in the method "DivHasError". How is it best way possible?

Comment: P.S. ":has" selector could be a solution
`div:has(.ng-invalid) .div-text  {color: red;} `
... but it is not yet supported by firefox, if I am right...

Comment: P.P.S. No, the ":has" is not a good solution, if the presentation of the validation status is supposed to be somewhere outside the div itself.

Comment: The form or formgroup has also a valid property. You can bind the class to it.

Comment: @derstauner, indeed, it would be a solution, but then I will need to group the fields physically in the FormGroups and as a result, the structure of the Form and DTO-objects will be very different.

Answer (score 0):

why not simply ?

div.ng-invalid, input.ng-invalid {border-color: red;}

basically on all invalid fields Angular will add an ng-invalid class, so just list them in your CSS

https://angular.io/guide/form-validation
=> look at Control status CSS classes

Comment: The div.ng-invalid will not be set for the surrounding div. Only the input.ng-invalid will be for particular inputs. My goal is to show the aggregated status from multiple fields. As I mentioned, with some restrictions the ":has" selector could help, but it is still not available in firefox.

Comment: ok, then use Javascript.
1. Fire a function when user leaves a certain field (blur event)
2. In your function, select parentNode or use 'closest'
3. Add desired style to your element

Comment: It will not work for multiple fields. There is an aggregational logic necessary: add the "highlight-style" if any of the multiple fields inside the div have the style ng-invalid and do not add, if all of them are valid. So, if I remove the highlight-style when single control becomes valid, the whole group may still be invalid because of other fields. And that is actually a point: I want to include all the fields in the logic, without listing them manually.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have solved it in a pretty straightforward way.
Below is a helper function that checks if any fields in the div are invalid.

```
function ExtractControls(form: FormGroup, elements:Element[], path: string[], controls: AbstractControl[]) {
  for (let child of elements) {
    const formGroupName = child.getAttribute('formGroupName');
    const formControlName = child.getAttribute('formControlName');
    const fieldPath = formGroupName ? [...path, formGroupName] : path;
    if (formControlName) {
      const field = form.get([...fieldPath, formControlName]);
      if (field) {
        controls.push(field)
      }
    }
    if (child.children.length > 0) {
      ExtractControls(form, Array.from(child.children), fieldPath, controls);
    }
  }
}

export function DivHasError(formGroup: FormGroup, div:HTMLDivElement): boolean {
  const controls: AbstractControl[] = [];
  ExtractControls(formGroup, Array.from(div.children), [], controls);
  for (let control of controls) {
    if (!control.valid) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

and HTML

```
<div class="div-address" [class.div-error]="DivHasError(form, divAddress)" #divAddress>
```

I am not sure about performance, I feel it is a bit too much logic for a validation, but for a first glance looks OK.